# Importing large PBI reports to group workspace with New-PowerBIReport error: 'A task was canceled.'

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'm using New-PowerBIReport cmdlet in a loop to import .pbix files from my local drive to group workspaces.

When the pbix file is large, I get the following error, outputted by these commands (Even after multiple retries on the same file I get the same error):

```
            Write-Host $_.Exception
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
```

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Imports.<UploadFile>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Imports.<PostImportFileWithHttpMessage>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.ImportsExtensions.PostImportWithFileInGroup(IImports operations, String groupId, Stream fileStream, String datasetDisplayName, String nameConflict, Nullable 1 skipReport)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.ReportsClient.PostImportForWorkspace(Guid workspaceId, String datasetDisplayName, String filePath, ImportConflictHandlerModeEnum nameConflict)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.ReportsClient.PostReportForWorkspace(Guid workspaceId, String reportName, String filePath, ImportConflictHandlerModeEnum nameConflict, Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Reports.NewPowerBIReport.ExecuteCmdlet()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Common.PowerBICmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

Error in terminal when this happens:

```
New-PowerBIReport : A task was canceled.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PowerBIReport -Path "C:\Path to my file ..."
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...ewPowerBIReport:NewPowerBIReport) [New-PowerBIReport], TaskCanceledException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A task was canceled.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Reports.NewPowerBIReport
```

I can see this uses `Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.ImportsExtensions.PostImportWithFileInGroup`, so I looked that up and found a similar method under Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2 called `PostImportWithFileAsyncInGroup`.

However I can't see an option with New-PowerBIReport to run this async. What is my best option to ensure larger files get imported to group workspaces? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my script from a VM within Azure and the problems disappeared. reason: Azure-Azure throughputs are a lot faster